# Multiple Table Join, inner join vs Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, join, exists

I am having issue getting the right query for a task. Lets say we have 4 tables with following columns

```
Table  Column   Column

one    abc

two    abc      cde

three  cde      def

four   def      dt
```

Now the column dt in table four is a Date datatype.

I am trying to get all the data from table one where date in the dt is greater than say 2012/01/01. columns abc, cde and def are related

I am doing something like this:

```
Select * 
from one t 
where Exists (Select a.abc 
              from two a 
              where a.abc = t.abc 
                and Exists (Select b.cde, b.def 
                            from three b 
                            where b.cde = a.cde 
                              and Exists (select c.def
                                          from four c 
                                          where c.def= b.def 
                                            abd c.dt >= toDate('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                         )
                           )
              );
```

I tried the same thing using inner join, But the inner join is giving row count that is actually more that the table has in some cases. Basically its duplicating the rows. Any help is much appreciated. I looked at distinct as well, looks like it increases the cost.

Comment: Can you provide the actual table structure and which columns are related/foreign keys please? The inner join you had sounds correct but you probably just need to change it to a left or right join. It would be good for you to provide that aswell.

Comment: i made some changes, does it help?

Answer (score 1):

That could be done like this. Can't see how you did it to give you more rows than the table count:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM one t1
INNER JOIN two t2 ON t2.abc = t1.abc
INNER JOIN three t3 ON t3.cde = t2.cde
INNER JOIN four t4 ON t4.def = t3.def
WHERE t4.dt >= toDate('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was doing using inner join. In some case i have these columns that are not  unique. Say in table two there is multiple rows with same value in column abc.

Comment: Ah. In that case it is understandable that it would give duplicate results. To handle that, i think you can get better performance with distinct or GROUP BY than with the query you are doing.

Comment: I tried distinct, its increasing the cost a lot, can you show how to do that using GROUP BY?

Comment: Just add group by all columns in table one.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Felipe Silva's answer, you can put the where .. in statement on the outer layer to remove the duplicates

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM one t1 where t1.abc in (
  select t2.abc from two t2 
  INNER JOIN three t3 ON t3.cde = t2.cde
  INNER JOIN four t4 ON t4.def = t3.def
  WHERE t4.dt >= toDate('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

Comment: Hey looks like a great idea i will try this tomorrow and update you.